# How to write a cron expression for quartz.net?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I need to run one application first Wednesday of every month at 4 AM.

```
Seconds - 0
Minutes - 0
Hours - 4
Day of Month - *
Month - [I dont know]
Day of Week - 4
Year -
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should do: `0 0 4 ? 1/1 WED#1 *`
You can build your own expressions using [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Thats the answer:-

0 0 4 ? * 4#1